# Get "Error starting DynamicEnvironmentComponent." in staring OpsCenter 6.5 agents.DSE 6.0.1

Tags: cassandra, datastax, jmx, datastax-enterprise, opscenter

After using [Adding an existing cluster](https://docs.datastax.com/en/opscenter/6.5/opsc/online_help/opscAddingCluster_t.html) to add DSE(6.0.1) cluster to OpsCenter, and select install agent automatically after all agents installed I have something like below picture in OpsCenter(version 6.5):

[image]

As you see *MONITORED DSE* is down.
When see log of agent see below error :

```
INFO [async-dispatch-1] 2018-07-02 15:37:30,962 Starting system.
INFO [async-dispatch-1] 2018-07-02 15:37:30,966 Starting DynamicEnvironmentComponent
WARN [async-dispatch-1] 2018-07-02 15:37:30,987 Exception while processing JMX data: java.lang.NullPointerException
ERROR [async-dispatch-1] 2018-07-02 15:37:30,988 Error starting DynamicEnvironmentComponent.
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at clojure.java.io$as_relative_path.invokeStatic(io.clj:414)
    at clojure.java.io$file.invokeStatic(io.clj:426)
    at clojure.java.io$file.invoke(io.clj:418)
    at opsagent.environment.collection$cassandra_yaml_location__GT_install_location.invokeStatic(collection.clj:128)
    at opsagent.environment.collection$cassandra_yaml_location__GT_install_location.invoke(collection.clj:119)
    at opsagent.environment.dynamic$dynamic_env_state.invokeStatic(dynamic.clj:151)
    at opsagent.environment.dynamic$dynamic_env_state.invoke(dynamic.clj:148)
    at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:171)
    at clojure.lang.AFn.applyTo(AFn.java:144)
    at clojure.core$apply.invokeStatic(core.clj:652)
    at clojure.core$partial$fn__4765.doInvoke(core.clj:2534)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:397)
    at opsagent.jmx$create_jmx_pool_with_config$wrapper__5941.doInvoke(jmx.clj:239)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:410)
    at opsagent.environment.dynamic$add_dynamic_state.invokeStatic(dynamic.clj:276)
    at opsagent.environment.dynamic$add_dynamic_state.invoke(dynamic.clj:264)
    at opsagent.environment.dynamic.DynamicEnvironmentComponent.start(dynamic.clj:299)
    at com.stuartsierra.component$fn__2593$G__2587__2595.invoke(component.clj:4)
    at com.stuartsierra.component$fn__2593$G__2586__2598.invoke(component.clj:4)
    at clojure.lang.Var.invoke(Var.java:379)
    at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:154)
    at clojure.lang.Var.applyTo(Var.java:700)
    at clojure.core$apply.invokeStatic(core.clj:648)
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:641)
    at com.stuartsierra.component$try_action.invokeStatic(component.clj:116)
    at com.stuartsierra.component$try_action.invoke(component.clj:115)
    at clojure.lang.Var.invoke(Var.java:401)
    at opsagent.config_service$update_system$fn__22445.invoke(config_service.clj:223)
    at clojure.lang.ArraySeq.reduce(ArraySeq.java:114)
    at clojure.core$reduce.invokeStatic(core.clj:6544)
    at clojure.core$reduce.invoke(core.clj:6527)
    at opsagent.config_service$update_system.invokeStatic(config_service.clj:217)
    at opsagent.config_service$update_system.doInvoke(config_service.clj:213)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:425)
    at opsagent.config_service$start_system_BANG_.invokeStatic(config_service.clj:243)
    at opsagent.config_service$start_system_BANG_.invoke(config_service.clj:236)
    at opsagent.config_service$fn__22551$fn__22552$state_machine__4942__auto____22553$fn__22555.invoke(config_service.clj:266)
    at opsagent.config_service$fn__22551$fn__22552$state_machine__4942__auto____22553.invoke(config_service.clj:266)
    at clojure.core.async.impl.ioc_macros$run_state_machine.invokeStatic(ioc_macros.clj:973)
    at clojure.core.async.impl.ioc_macros$run_state_machine.invoke(ioc_macros.clj:972)
    at clojure.core.async.impl.ioc_macros$run_state_machine_wrapped.invokeStatic(ioc_macros.clj:977)
    at clojure.core.async.impl.ioc_macros$run_state_machine_wrapped.invoke(ioc_macros.clj:975)
    at clojure.core.async$ioc_alts_BANG_$fn__5131.invoke(async.clj:384)
    at clojure.core.async$do_alts$fn__5085$fn__5088.invoke(async.clj:253)
    at clojure.core.async.impl.channels.ManyToManyChannel$fn__754.invoke(channels.clj:265)
    at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:22)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
INFO [async-dispatch-1] 2018-07-02 15:37:30,991 Finished starting system.
```

what's problem? Does anyone have an idea? How can I fix it?

Comment: i have this problem, thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved it, this error occurs when OpsCenter can't find config of DSE in another word OpsCenter agent can't find DSE when you installing DSE via tarball,  you should not install DSE in `/etc/dse` or `/etc/*` because when you install DSE by package it uses this directory and when you use it in tarball installation become confused, it's bug of DSE installation if you change installation directory to `/opt` or another, the problem is solved.